# Resize the Images Created from Bytes

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, image-resizing

I have multiple images on my website. But the images generate from bytes stored in the database. I generated the  images from the byes and displaying it on my website. But he size of the images are very large(70 kg)per image. This is making slow down my site.

Is There any way to resize these images (12 kg). Please help me if anyone have solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom handler that can create and return image. Along with that handler should set the changeability settings etc along with image re-sizing in order to get performance improvements.

Here is the one for example: http://webimageresizer.codeplex.com/

// Returns the image mapping to /bla.jpg resized to width of 100 pixels preserving aspect relative to height
http://webimageresizer.codeplex.com/ImageHandler.ashx?src=/bla.jpg&width=100

Let me know if you need more help.